# Table closing after populating data passed as props from a modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog

I'm passing data from am AddItem modal in react to a table in  the NewInvoice component. The data is being populated to the table successfully but modal does not close after clicking the save button. Kindly assist on what i could be missing on this.

NewInvoice.js

```
  const [itemOpen, setitemOpen] = useState(false);

  <div className="new-invoice-client">
              <FormDataTable itemOpen={itemOpen}/>
          
            </div>
            <div
              className="new-item-links"
              style={{ marginLeft: "35px", marginTop: "35px" }}
            >
              <Button onClick={() => setitemOpen(true)}>
                <BsPlus />
                Add an Item
                {itemOpen && <AddItem setitemOpen={setitemOpen} />}
              </Button>
            </div>
```

The `<FormInvoiceTable/>`  is  passed to the NewInvoice parent component as shown below.

FormInvoieTable.js

```
function FormDataTable(props) {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  // console.log(tableData)

  const tableRows = tableData.map((value, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{value.item}</td>
        <td>{value.amount}</td>
        <td>{value.rate}</td>
        <td>{value.quantity}</td>
        <td>{value.description}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });
  const addRows = (data) => {
    const totalData = tableData.length;
    data.id = totalData + 1;
    const updatedtableData = [...tableData];
    updatedtableData.push(data);
    setTableData(updatedtableData);
  };

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <table className="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Rate</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>
      </table>

 <AddItem func={addRows}/>}
     </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

AddItem.js Modal

```
function AddItem(props) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const [rate, setRate] = useState("");
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");

  const clearState = () => {
    setItem("");
    setAmount("");
    setRate("");
    setQuantity("");
    setDescription("");
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formInputData = {
      item,
      amount,
      rate,
      quantity,
      description,
    };
    props.func(formInputData);
   // clearState();
   props.setitemOpen(false)
  };

  return (
   <div className="modalBackground">
      <div className="modalContainer">
        <div className="title">
          <h1>New Item</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="modal-form-container">
          <form className="register-form">
            <input
              className="register-input"
              name="item"
              onChange={(e) => setItem(e.target.value)}
              value={item}
              placeholder="Item"
            />

            <input
              className="register-input"
              name="amount"
              value={amount}
              placeholder="Amount"
              onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
            />

            <input
              className="register-input"
              placeholder="Rate"
              name="rate"
              value={rate}
              onChange={(e) => setRate(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
              className="register-input"
              name="quantity"
              placeholder="Quantity"
              value={quantity}
              onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
            />

            <input
              className="register-input"
              style={{ width: "600px", height: "80px" }}
              type="text"
              value={description}
              placeholder="Description"
              onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
            />

            <div className="modal-buttons" style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>
              <button onClick={() => props.setitemOpen(false)}>cancel</button>
            </div>
          </form>
         

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your are creating component `<AddItem/>` two times.

When you create it in `FormDataTable` component you don't pass it prop `setitemOpen`. You are passing only `addRows` function as a prop :

```
 <AddItem func={addRows}/>
```

One solution would be to pass `setitemOpen={setitemOpen}` prop to `FormDataTable` component and call it in `addRow` method with argument `false`. Also, remove `AddItem` component from `NewInvoice` component and create it only in `FormDataTable` component based on `itemOpen`

Here is code snippet:
**NewInvoice.jsx**

```
 import React from "react";
import FormDataTable from "./FormInvoieTable";
import { useState } from "react";
import Button from "@mui/material/Button";
export default function NewInvoice(props) {
  const [itemOpen, setitemOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="new-invoice-client">
        <FormDataTable itemOpen={itemOpen} setitemOpen={setitemOpen} />
      </div>
      <div
        className="new-item-links"
        style={{ marginLeft: "35px", marginTop: "35px" }}
      >
        <Button onClick={() => setitemOpen(true)}>Add an Item</Button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Then in FormDataTable component, modify `addRows` method like this:
**FormDataTable.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import AddItem from "./AddItem";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function FormDataTable(props) {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);
  const { itemOpen } = props;
  const tableRows = tableData.map((value, index) => {
    return (
      <tr key={index}>
        <td>{value.item}</td>
        <td>{value.amount}</td>
        <td>{value.rate}</td>
        <td>{value.quantity}</td>
        <td>{value.description}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  });

      const addRows = (data) => {
        const totalData = tableData.length;
        data.id = totalData + 1;
        const updatedtableData = [...tableData];
        updatedtableData.push(data);
        setTableData(updatedtableData);
        props.setitemOpen(false);
      };
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <table className="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Rate</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>{tableRows}</tbody>
          </table>
    
          {itemOpen && <AddItem func={addRows} />}
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
```

**AddItem.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function AddItem(props) {
  const [item, setItem] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");
  const [rate, setRate] = useState("");
  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState("");
  const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
  console.log(props);
  const clearState = () => {
    setItem("");
    setAmount("");
    setRate("");
    setQuantity("");
    setDescription("");
  };
  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const formInputData = {
      item,
      amount,
      rate,
      quantity,
      description,
    };
    props.func(formInputData);
    // clearState();
  };

  return (
    <div className="modalBackground">
      <div className="modalContainer">
        <div className="title">
          <h1>New Item</h1>
        </div>

        <div className="modal-form-container">
          <form className="register-form">
            <input
              className="register-input"
              name="item"
              onChange={(e) => setItem(e.target.value)}
              value={item}
              placeholder="Item"
            />

            <input
              className="register-input"
              name="amount"
              value={amount}
              placeholder="Amount"
              onChange={(e) => setAmount(e.target.value)}
            />

            <input
              className="register-input"
              placeholder="Rate"
              name="rate"
              value={rate}
              onChange={(e) => setRate(e.target.value)}
            />
            <input
              className="register-input"
              name="quantity"
              placeholder="Quantity"
              value={quantity}
              onChange={(e) => setQuantity(e.target.value)}
            />

            <input
              className="register-input"
              style={{ width: "600px", height: "80px" }}
              type="text"
              value={description}
              placeholder="Description"
              onChange={(e) => setDescription(e.target.value)}
            />

            <div className="modal-buttons" style={{ justifyContent: "center" }}>
              <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Save</button>
              <button onClick={() => props.setitemOpen(false)}>cancel</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: The <FormDataTable/>  component is being rendered everytime the NewInvoice component is rendered hence the modal is open.

Comment: I made typo, I accidentaly left AddItem component in NewInvoice.jsx file.Should be created only once, in FrontInvoiceTable.jsx. I updataed answer, should work now